# MYSQL Query, where statement within SELECT (to have multiple lines/where statements)

Tags: mysql, database

So I used to have 10 queries, same SELECT statement, different WHERE. One query looked like this:

```
SELECT 
    workdate AS `Date`,
    DAYNAME(workdate) AS `Day`,
    COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM((CASE
                    WHEN
                        paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0'
                    then
                        (IF(historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` = 0,
                            (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Base Rate` * 2.0)),
                            (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` * 2.0))))
                    WHEN paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours * historyemployeepay.`Base Rate`)
                    WHEN
                        paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5'
                            OR paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0'
                    then
                        (IF(historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` = 0,
                            (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Base Rate` * 1.5)),
                            (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` * 1.5))))
                end)),
                2),
            0) AS `Amount`
FROM
    otherrates,
    employeedata
        INNER JOIN
    employeehours ON employeedata.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
        JOIN
    historyemployeepay ON employeehours.employeeid = historyemployeepay.EmployeeID
WHERE
    shift = 'PM' AND DriverDock = 'Driv'
        AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%'
        AND DAYNAME(workdate) <> 'Saturday'
        AND historyemployeepay.FromDate <= employeehours.workdate
        AND (historyemployeepay.ToDate IS NULL
        OR employeehours.workdate <= historyemployeepay.ToDate)
GROUP BY workdate
```

I want to have them all on a website page and if I do so individually, the website page takes ages to load... So I thought of a great idea to try and link them together, as below. Please note I've taken out eight of the lines in the SELECT statement, leaving only two for the example.

How can I get this to work? It does not display correct values (null), have I done something wrong?

```
SELECT 
    workdate AS `Date`,
    DAYNAME(workdate) AS `Day`,
    (CASE
        WHEN
            shift = 'AM' AND DriverDock = 'Driv'
                AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%'
        then
            COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM((CASE
                            WHEN
                                paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0'
                            then
                                (IF(historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` = 0,
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Base Rate` * 2.0)),
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` * 2.0))))
                            WHEN paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours * historyemployeepay.`Base Rate`)
                            WHEN
                                paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5'
                                    OR paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0'
                            then
                                (IF(historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` = 0,
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Base Rate` * 1.5)),
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` * 1.5))))
                        end)),
                        2),
                    0)
    end) AS `AMPERMDRIV`,
    (CASE
        WHEN
            shift = 'AM' AND DriverDock = 'Dock'
                AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%'
        then
            COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM((CASE
                            WHEN
                                paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0'
                            then
                                (IF(historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` = 0,
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Base Rate` * 2.0)),
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` * 2.0))))
                            WHEN paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours * historyemployeepay.`Base Rate`)
                            WHEN
                                paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5'
                                    OR paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0'
                            then
                                (IF(historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` = 0,
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Base Rate` * 1.5)),
                                    (employeehours * (historyemployeepay.`Other Rate` * 1.5))))
                        end)),
                        2),
                    0)
    end) AS `AMPERMDOCK`
FROM
    otherrates,
    employeedata
        INNER JOIN
    employeehours ON employeedata.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
        JOIN
    historyemployeepay ON employeehours.employeeid = historyemployeepay.EmployeeID
WHERE
    DAYNAME(workdate) <> 'Saturday'
        AND historyemployeepay.FromDate <= employeehours.workdate
        AND (historyemployeepay.ToDate IS NULL
        OR employeehours.workdate <= historyemployeepay.ToDate)
GROUP BY workdate
```

Have a look at the result:

[image]

Comment: why is the conditional test on `shift`, `DriverDock` outside of the SUM aggregate? ... is the intent really to evaluate those after the aggregate? (doesn't look right to me).  Why is the COALESCE and TRUNCATE not performed after evaluation of the CASE which could return NULL? And why the CROSS JOIN operation to `otherrates` table,   does it contain only a single row, and why the comma syntax for the join? assigning short aliases to the tables can make the qualified column references shorter, and a lot of the column references aren't qualified, we can't tell what table those columns are from;

Comment: why the second test for '03 Overtime 2.0', that was already caught in an earlier WHEN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE expressions have an implied ELSE NULL, and you don't have a COALESCE catching the NULL on the outermost CASE.

The evaluation of non-aggregates not included in the GROUP BY, after the calculation of the aggregate, that just doesn't look right; looks like it will return "wrong" results.

I think you want something more like this:

```
SELECT h.workdate AS `Date`
     , DAYNAME(h.workdate) AS `Day`
     , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN (shift="AM" AND DriverDock = 'Driv' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%')
           THEN
             CASE
             WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
               THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
             WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
               THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
             WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
               THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
             END
         END
       ),2),0) AS `AMPERMDRIV`
     , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN (shift="AM" AND DriverDock = 'Dock' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%')
           THEN
             CASE 
             WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
               THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
             WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
               THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
             WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
               THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
             END
         END
       ),2),0) AS `AMPERMDOCK`
  FROM employeedata d
  JOIN employeehours h
    ON d.`ID Number` = h.employeeid
  JOIN historyemployeepay p
    ON (h.employeeid = p.EmployeeID)
   AND (h.workdate >= p.FromDate)
   AND (h.workdate <= p.ToDate OR p.ToDate IS NULL)
 CROSS  
  JOIN otherrates r
 WHERE DAYNAME(h.workdate) <> 'Saturday'
 GROUP BY h.workdate
```

I would qualify all the column references, if I knew which table the columns were coming from.

Comment: Thank you Spencer, that is perfect. I do have one more issue, maybe you can help? Please look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394073/mysql-query-convert-row-to-columns-with-complex-query