# PHP and Mysql query, use PHP to convert row to columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, pivot-table

I think this is beyond me, I want to convert my MYSQL query so that it displays rows and columns exactly like this:
[image]

This is what I have created with a MYSQL query:
[image]

Here is the actual query to create this:

```
SELECT h.workdate AS `Date`
 , DAYNAME(h.workdate) AS `Day`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='AM' AND DriverDock = 'Driv' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%')
       THEN
         CASE
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `AMPERMDRIV`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='AM' AND DriverDock = 'Dock' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `AMPERMDOCK`
  , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='AM' AND DriverDock = 'Driv' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Cas%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `AMCASUDRIV`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='AM' AND DriverDock = 'Dock' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Cas%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `AMCASUDOCK`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='AM' AND DriverDock = 'Driv' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%AGENT%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `AMAGENTDRIV`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='AM' AND DriverDock = 'Dock' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%AGENT%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `AMAGENTDOCK`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='PM' AND DriverDock = 'Driv' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `PMPERMDRIV`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='PM' AND DriverDock = 'Dock' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Perm%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `PMPERMDOCK`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='PM' AND DriverDock = 'Dock' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%Cas%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `PMCASUDOCK`
 , COALESCE(TRUNCATE(SUM(
     CASE
     WHEN (shift='PM' AND DriverDock = 'Dock' AND `Salary Code Description` LIKE '%AGENT%')
       THEN
         CASE 
         WHEN paycode IN ('03 Overtime 2.0')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 2.0)
         WHEN paycode IN ('02 Overtime 1.5')
           THEN (employeehours * IF(p.`Other Rate`=0,p.`Base Rate`,p.`Other Rate`) * 1.5)
         WHEN paycode IN ('01 Ordinary')
           THEN (employeehours * p.`Base Rate`)
         END
     END
   ),2),0) AS `PMAGENTDOCK`
FROM employeedata d
JOIN employeehours h
ON d.`ID Number` = h.employeeid
JOIN historyemployeepay p
ON (h.employeeid = p.EmployeeID)
AND (h.workdate >= p.FromDate)
AND (h.workdate <= p.ToDate OR p.ToDate IS NULL)
CROSS  
JOIN otherrates r
WHERE DAYNAME(h.workdate) <> 'Saturday'
GROUP BY h.workdate
```

I have the following html table, how do I loop through the query results and display correctly?:

```
<?php
  $querydailyoperations=mysql_query("
                                     QUERY ABOVE
  ");
while($querydailyoperationsshow=mysql_fetch_array($querydailyoperations)){ echo "??????????";};
?>
```

and:

```
<tr><td class="greencell">AM</td><td class="greencell">PERMANENT</td><td class="greencell">DRIVER</td>5x td here, input from above query...
</tr>
<tr><td class="greencell">AM</td><td class="greencell">PERMANENT</td><td class="dbluecell">DH</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="greencell">AM</td><td class="orangecell">CASUAL</td><td class="greencell">DRIVER</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="greencell">AM</td><td class="orangecell">CASUAL</td><td class="dbluecell">DH</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="greencell">AM</td><td nowrap class="redcell">AGENT LABOUR</td><td class="greencell">DRIVER</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="greencell">AM</td><td nowrap class="redcell">AGENT LABOUR</td><td class="dbluecell">DH</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="bluecell">PM</td><td class="greencell">PERMANENT</td><td class="greencell">DRIVER</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="bluecell">PM</td><td class="greencell">PERMANENT</td><td class="dbluecell">DH</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="bluecell">PM</td><td class="orangecell">CASUAL</td><td class="dbluecell">DH</td> etc...
</tr>
<tr><td class="bluecell">PM</td><td nowrap class="redcell">AGENT LABOUR</td><td class="dbluecell">DH</td> etc...
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, this has nothing to do with your MySQL query.  The proper way to format the data the way you want is using PHP to loop through and build out the HTML to desired specs and use CSS to achieve the look and feel.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do as well, but I can't seem to get my head around it, I will add in that coding.. Thanks brian

Comment: No problem, edit your question and post what code you do have and I'll help you sort it out.

Comment: mysql_query and related functions are today obsolete and will be removed in future versions of PHP, you should think about moving on to PDO or MySQLi. I also recommend taking a look at Example #2 on this PHP page that demonstrates a way of doing what you want to do : http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Cuonic, that does look like what I want to do, but I do not have that much php experience to have an idea how to use it...!

Comment: @atomapps: please, Please, PLEASE! qualify ALL column references with the alias assigned to the table e.g. "`d.employeehours`" in place of "`employeehours`", "`h.paycode`" in place of "`paycode`". (I'd have done that for you, but I don't know which columns come from which tables, the poor reader can't tell without looking at the schema definition, to find which table the column is defined. And just as importantly, if a column named `paycode` is added to one of the tables in the query, the query will start throwing an error due to "ambiguous column". Qualifying column references fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the result using a SQL query, but it's not trivial.

---

But before you go that route, I recommend you consider an different approach.

Since the query is returning a relatively small set of rows, you could instead retrieve the entire result set into PHP as a two dimensional array.

Consider a fairly simple case, as an illustration:

```
SELECT foo, fee, fi, fo, fum
  FROM mytable 
 ORDER BY foo

foo fee fi  fo  fum
--- --- --- --- ---
ABC   2   3   5   7
DEF  11  13  17  19
```

We could do a fetchAll, and get a two dimensional array, then loop through the array and retrieve the values column-wise, rather than row-wise. One option is to transform the array we receive into a new arrays that look like this:

```
bar  ABC  DEF
---  ---  ---
fee    2   11
fi     3   13
fo     5   17
fum    7   19
```

It's not really necessary to do the transformation, you could walk the original array. But separating the transformation out as a separate step would probably make your code a little easier, when you get to actually generating the output into the page. (It seems like a common enough problem that someone has probably written a function that does the array transformation you want. I don't think there's a PHP builtin that does it.

headings:

```
array { [0]=>'bar'  [1]=>'ABC'  [2]=>'DEF' }
```

rows:

```
array {
  [0]=>array { [0]=>'fee'   [1]=>'2'  [2]=>'11' }
  [1]=>array { [0]=>'fi'    [1]=>'3'  [2]=>'13' }
  [2]=>array { [0]=>'fo'    [1]=>'5'  [2]=>'17' }
  [3]=>array { [0]=>'fum'   [1]=>'7'  [2]=>'19' }
}
```

For a small set of rows like you have, I would opt to do this in the PHP rather than in SQL.

---

But you asked how to do it in SQL. As I said earlier, it's not trivial.

SQL requires that the SELECT statement define every column to be returned; the number and types of the columns can't be dymanic when the statement executes.

If we build another query (apart from the original query) that defines the columns, and returns the rows we expect returned with placeholders for the values, we are halfway there. All that remains is to do an outer join to the rows returned by the original query, and conditionally return the column values on the appropriate rows.

This approach works if you have a pre-defined set of rows and columns we need returned, especially when the original row source is sparse, and we need to generate the "missing" rows. (For example, getting counts of products ordered, and there are a lot of missing rows, there's not a good way to generate the missing rows.

For example:

```
SELECT r.bar
     , '' AS `ABC`
     , '' AS `DEF`
  FROM ( SELECT 'fee' AS bar
          UNION ALL SELECT 'fi'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'fo'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'fum'
       ) r
 GROUP BY r.bar
```

That will return:

```
 bar  ABC  DEF
 ---  ---  ---
 fee
 fi
 fo
 fum
```

So, that gets us all of the columns defined, and all of the rows we want to return. The first column is populated. That query doesn't really need the GROUP BY yet, but we are going to need it once we match to the rows in from the "real" source result set.

The "trick" now is matching the rows from our source, and returning the value from a column based on the appropriate conditions.

What we are going to generate, essentially is a result set that looks like this:

```
bar  foo  ABC  DEF
---  ---  ---  ---
fee  ABC    2
fee  DEF        11
fi   ABC    3
fi   DEF        13
fo   ABC    5
fo   DEF        15
fum  ABC    7
fum  DEF        17
```

Then we are going to "collapse" the rows, by removing the foo column from the resultset and doing a GROUP BY on `bar`. We are going to use an aggregate function (either MAX or SUM) taking advantage of the handling they do with NULL values, to produce a result like this this:

```
bar  foo  ABC  DEF
---  ---  ---  ---
fee         2   11
fi          3   13
fo          5   15
fum         7   17
```

Using this rather unwieldy SQL:

```
SELECT r.bar
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.foo = 'ABC' THEN CASE r.bar 
         WHEN 'fee' THEN t.fee 
         WHEN 'fi'  THEN t.fi
         WHEN 'fo'  THEN t.fo
         WHEN 'fum' THEN t.fum
       END END) AS 'ABC'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.foo = 'DEF' THEN CASE r.bar 
         WHEN 'fee' THEN t.fee 
         WHEN 'fi'  THEN t.fi
         WHEN 'fo'  THEN t.fo
         WHEN 'fum' THEN t.fum
       END END) AS 'DEF'
  FROM ( SELECT 'foo' AS col
          UNION ALL SELECT 'fee'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'fi'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'fo'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'fum'
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN mysource t
 GROUP BY r.bar
```

---

Note that `mysource` in the query above can be replaced with an inline view, wrapping parens around a suitable query that returns the rows we want.

The inline view aliased as `r` is our source for returning the rows we want to return.

The expressions in the SELECT list are doing the conditional tests, to pick out the right values for each column in each row.

Given the regular pattern of the CASE statements, it's possible to use some SQL to help generate the query, but that has to be done as a separate step. The output from that SQL can be used to help form the actual query we need.

In your case, given that `workdate` is what you want to use for the column header, this is likely going to have to be dynamically generated. (You could drop that second column 'day of week' column from the original source query, and move that to the outer query.

If I didn't know the `workdate` values for the headings before I ran the query, then I'd opt to create a TEMPORARY TABLE and populate it with results from the original query, and then query the temporary table, to get the `workdate` headers, and the "first column" to generate the rows. Then I'd run the actual query against the temporary table.

---

To repeat, I think you'd be better off doing the transform/pivot of the results from your original query in PHP, rather than trying to do it in SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You could try GROUP_CONCAT

Also referenced here [Transpose Rows to Headers in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619784/transpose-rows-to-headers-in-mysql) and here [Pivot table basics: rows to columns](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78)